# Ordered insertion working sporadically with primitive types & strings

Tags: data-structures, comparable, insertion-sort

For an assignment, we've been asked to implement both ordered and unordered versions of LinkedLists as Bags in Java.  The ordered versions will simply extend the unordered implmentations while overriding the insertion methods.

The ordering on insertion function works... somewhat.  Given a test array of

```
String[] testArray= {"z","g","x","v","y","t","s","r","w","q"};
```

the output is

```
q w r s t y v x g z
```

when it should be

```
g q r s t v w x y z
```

However, the ordering works fine when the elements aren't mixed up in value.  For example, I originally used the `testArray[]` above with the alphabe reversed, and the ordering was exactly as it should be.

My add function is

```
@Override
public void add(E e){
    Iter iter= new Iter(head.prev);
    int compValue;
    E currentItem= null;

    //empty list, add at first position
    if (size < 1)
        iter.add(e);

    else {

        while (iter.hasNext()){
            currentItem= iter.next(); //gets next item

            //saves on multiple compareTo calls
            compValue= e.compareTo(currentItem); 

            //adds at given location
            if (compValue <= 0)
                iter.add(e, iter.index);

            else //moves on
                currentItem= iter.next();
        }
    }
}
```

The iterator functionality is implemented as

```
//decided to use iterator to simplify method functionality
protected class Iter implements Iterator<E>, ListIterator<E>{
    protected int index= 0;
    protected Node current= null;

//Sets a new iterator to the index point provided
    public Iter(int index){
        current= head.next;
        this.index=0;
        while (index > nextIndex()) //moves on to the index point
            next();
    }

public void add(E e, int index){
        size++;

        Iter iterator= new Iter(index);

        Node node= new Node();
        Node current= iterator.current.prev;

        node.next= current.next;
        node.prev= current;
        node.next.prev= node;
        node.prev.next= node;

        node.item= e;
    }
```

As it is right now, the only things being used are primitive types.  I know for objects, a specific comparable class will have to be written, but in this case, String contains a compareTo() method that should give correct ordering.

By chance, a classmate of mine has a similar implementation and is returning the same results.

Using natural ordering, how can I resolve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

Three things about your add() function jump out at me:

1. It should exit the loop as soon as it inserts the new value; this might not actually be a problem, but it is inefficient to keep looking
2. You call next_item at the top of the loop, but call it AGAIN if the value isn't added
3. If your list has just 1 value in it, and you try to add a value larger than the one currently in the list, won't the new value fail to be added?